# When should spaces be provided and when not in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

I am really confused as to when should one provided spaces between any operator or operand and when not. I have often encountered this problem which gives error on running.

Comment: Are there any particular syntax questions? This question is very open-ended. Edit your question to include some code.

Answer (score 1):

For the `if` command specifically, remember that `[` is not just syntax, [it is a command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/test.1.html). And all commands need to be separated from their arguments with whitespace.

Another common place of confusion is around grouping constructs: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping -- braces require spaces, parentheses don't.

In general, use more whitespace and you'll be OK.